# How can you add a class to the body tag if the page contains specific text with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, class, styles, addition

I'm building an eCommerce site and need to add a class to the body tag if the page contains a specific term, in this case, "Accessories." I've used this code to style the span that it appears in but I would need to wrap the whole page in a class to style certain elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("span:contains('Accessories')").addClass("newstyle");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just change `span` to `body`

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't specific enough because it will add to every page because Accessories is in other places such as the Menu or Footer, so it will add it to every page. Here's the thought process that I'm using and if there's a better way please enlighten me. The code that is outputed from the ecommerce platform that looks like this:

<span itemprop="name">Accessories by Type</span>

I would need to assign the span an id and class

Comment: You said "if the page contains a specific term". You didn't say the term had to be in a specific place.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still not having any luck adding the class to the body. You can see my page here: https://test97.mybigcommerce.com/avpf2-b-ash-vacuum-pre-filter/ preview code: 9jcfc6f675

Bigcommcerce doesn't have any ids or class based on the type of category. Theres no way to identify the products category on an actual product page. I know I'm making it confusing but the end results would be if a page contains a "<span itemprop="name" class="newaccessories">Accessories</span>" then add "newstyle" to the main body class.

Comment: Please update the question with those details. I've updated my answer to match it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:has()` to test if the body contains a specific element that contains `Accessories`

```
$("body:has(span[itemprop='name'].newaccessories:contains(Accessories))").addClass("newstyle");
```